# POWERSHELL: Problem with Exprt-DbaLogin: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: powershell

I am logged onto a windows server 2016, running sqlserver 2019, with a local instance(MSSQLSERVER) I'm trying to use powershell to export all logins to file using :

```
Export-DbaLogin -SqlInstance MSSQLSERVER -Path 'Desktop\login.sql'
```

when i run : `Test-DbaConnection -SqlInstance $Env:COMPUTERNAME`

it returns all good data execpt:

```
InstanceName         : MSSQLSERVER
SqlInstance          : xxxxxxx
SqlVersion           :
ConnectingAsUser     :
**ConnectSuccess       : False**
```

I have turned firewall off, enabled SQL Browser, and still receive :

```
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
The network path was not found
```

I am able to interrogate instance with commands such as:

```
$Databases = Get-ChildItem -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\default\Databases
$Databases.Script()
```

Successfully

I have turned firewall off, enabled SQL Browser, verified ipconfig /all has accurate data, checked ports,

```
IsPingable           : True
PSRemotingAccessible : True
```

but am baffled that the local instance connect status is false?

using

```
Version: 1.79.2 (user setup)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.14393
```